# Не собирается новый apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Обновил Android Studio до 3.1

Теперь при компиляции собирается (а скорее всего запускается) старый apk. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Это странно. Попробуйте почистить папочку с билдами руками, или же выполнить `gradle clean`, после чего собрать проект. И как вы собираете все это дело? Через конфигурацию в студии, или же через команды `gradle`?

Comment: @selya Чистил. Собираю через конфигурацию

Comment: Гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831082/android-studio-is-installing-old-apk-on-device)

Comment: @selya оформляйте 2 комментарий как ответ!:) Спасибо

Comment: Тут не принято давать ответы ссылками) Главное, что помог. Если хотите, можете сами дать ответ. Опишите, как решили проблему, и засчитайте его. Это будет куда лучше)